# How to rotate line in Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

Currently I'm trying to rotate a `line` that I draw in `canvas`. I managed to do that, but as I rotate them 360° the line in previous position does not disappear, so in the end I don't get just 1 line, but whole circle.

Here's my code:

This snippet is initiated with the launch of the app

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
p = new Paint();
p.setColor(Color.RED);
imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
p.setStrokeWidth(5);
canvas.drawLine(0, height/2, width, height/2, p);
```

And this piece - gets updated every sec.

```
canvas.rotate(refY, width/2, height/2);
canvas.drawLine(0, height/2, width, height/2, p);
btn.setText(Integer.toString(refY))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save and restore the canvas accordingly:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); //clear everything drawn to the bitmap
canvas.rotate(refY, width/2, height/2);
canvas.drawLine(0, height/2, width, height/2, p);
canvas.restore();
btn.setText(Integer.toString(refY))
```

Comment: Could you give more details on how you update `refY` and how you call the above code (_for example, from a Handler_)?

Comment: I thought you were wanting to have the lines always shown in the screen but it seems this is not the case. Could you clarify what have to happen when it gets 360º?

Comment: I want only 1 line present that rotates. But for that I need each previous line to be erased. Currently my code manages to draw rotation, but it does not erase line in previous position, thus creating a circle.

Comment: So you have to clear the previous contents and then draw the new one. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, that sounds great.

Comment: I updated the answer, check if the `drawColor` does what you want.

Comment: No, this won't do it either - I've got an image behind the line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93399/discussion-between-tato-rodrigo-and-oleksandr-firsov).